# How to change dataframe name programatically in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an array of dataframes . The idea is to programatically create a new array of dataframes that have the dataframe name appended with a string. To put it simply i have an array called

```
var dataFrameArray = Array(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10)
```

I need a new dataFrame called

```
newDataFrameArray = Array(df1new, df2new, df3new, df4new, df5new, df6new, df7new, df8new, df9new, df10new)
```

Where each element in the new Array is a dataframe with the new name df(x) + "new"

This is my attempt at my code that is not working as of now.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

var dataFrameArray = Array(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10)
var newDataFrameArray = new Array[Dataset](dataFrameArray.length);
var counter = 0;
for (x <- dataFrameArray) {
  var y: Dataset<Row> = x.select($"timestamp".cast(DoubleType).cast(TimestampType).as("timestamps"),$"is_anomaly",$"value")
  y = y.orderBy($"timestamps")
  y.printSchema()
  newDataFrameArray = newDataFrameArray + y
}

for (eachDf <- newDataFrameArray) {
  eachDf.printSchema
}
```

Comment: where is the question ? you've already the code that did what you want

Comment: The code is an attempt it is not working. Thanks for the negative vote :)

Comment: I just up voted the question, it's clearer now. I'll be working on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to change the variable names dynamically in Scala or Java.
The variable names are supposed to be declared explicitly.
Moreover, your problem here is related to Scala and has nothing to do with Spark Dataset

Answer (score 0):

You cant't change the name of dataframe variable. Instead of creating a new Dataframe you can register a new table and assign them in dataframe later

```
y.createOrReplaceTempView()
```